# Nodejs Mongoose - Serve clients a single query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, mongodb

I'm looking to implement a solution where I can query the Mongoose Database on a regular interval and then store the results to serve to my clients.

I'm assuming this will reduce my response time when my users pull the collection.

I attempted to implement this plan by creating an empty global object and then writing a function that queries the db and then stores the results as the global object mentioned previously. At the end of the function I setTimeout for 60 seconds and then ran the function again. I call this function the first time the server controller gets called when the app is first run.

I then set my clients up so that when they requested the collection, it would first look to see if the global object exists, and if so return that as the response. I figured this would cut my 7-10 second queries down to < 1 sec.

In my novice thinking I assumed that Nodejs being 'single-threaded' something like this could work quite well - but it just seemed to eat up all my RAM and cause fatal errors.

Am I on the right track with my thinking or is it better to query the db every time people pull the collection?

Here is the code in question:

```
var allLeads = {};

var getAllLeads = function(){
    allLeads = {};
    console.log('Getting All Leads...');
    Lead.find().sort('-lastCalled').exec(function(err, leads) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error getting leads');
        } else {

            allLeads = leads;
        }
    });

setTimeout(function(){
    getAllLeads();
  }, 60000);
};
getAllLeads();
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: If you set it up correctly it then shouldn't create a memory leak. Show the code in question.

Comment: only a code sample can help you here

Comment: Added code to the question